# How to formulate survey questions that will elicit unbiased answers?

Tags: sampling, survey

I'm doing a questionnaire on whether international student grants at my college are satisfactory (or not). Instead of asking them if it's enough (which they'll obviously say no) how can I formulate a set of questions that will get unbiased answers? Perhaps the result could also tell me how much more we would adjust the grant?

Comment: This question is more about the psychological side of psychometrics than the statistical side, so I think it's off-topic for this site.

Comment: Hmm Yeah, you're not wrong but it was part of my course "sampling theory" so I assumed there would be some experienced peeps that ran into the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could try https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kodiologist When did CV stop being about methodological (data collection) issues? I thought it used to be at least. Having said this I think it is a legitime question, i.e. how to ask question to avoid desirable answers is an ongoing field of methodological research.

Comment: @tomka It still is about that, but like I said, this question has more to do with substantive considerations than statistical considerations.

Comment: @Kodiologist I think methodological issues undertaken to address statistical problems (bias) are relevant. This post seems to fit the bill.  But to your point, the OP will likely find many different disciplines have their favorite "tricks" (no pun intended) to address these types of methodological problems.

Comment: @Lock The **trick** you are looking for is the  Warner's Randomized Response Technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask a series of question that are highly correlated with "sufficient grant money."  For example, you could ask questions like "During the past school year, did you have enough money to purchase all your textbooks when they were required?", "During the past school year, did you have to work a job while in school in order to pay for your school expenses," etc.  These questions individually and in aggregate essentially serve as a proxy for "sufficient grant money."  So for example, if most students say "no" and "yes" to the first and second example questions presented above, respectively, you could reasonably conclude that students did not have sufficient grant money.  By asking these questions, you've haven't even mentioned grant money so students are likely not to even make the connection that you are really trying to determine sufficiency of grant funding and should reduce bias.

You don't even have to "trick" respondents to find these answers either.

Comment: Maybe trick was a poor choice of wording. I just wanted to say how can I be indirect. I'll take this into consideration. THANKS!